# Filter for a word from a string in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am having 10 columns (don't bother columns) and more than 10,000 rows. The data in the rows are like:

Mens Black **Pindot** Skinny Fit Tuxedo Pants

Mens **Pink** Ribbed Muscle Fit Sweater

Mens Gold Look Bug Lapel **Pin**

Mens Black **Pin** Back Bow Tie

The problem is:
I want to filter just the "Pin" word. That means the filtered result should give me just last 2 rows as mentioned and not the rows that contains "Pinkdot" and "Pink"

Any help will be appreciated. THanks

Comment: Use `RegEx` object.

Comment: @ShaiRado would you please elaborate?

Comment: jsut a question,"Mens Black Pindot Skinny Fit Tuxedo Pants" is an exampke in one cell in a certain row ? or a few cells ? is each word in a different cell ?

Comment: @ShaiRado "Mens Black Pindot Skinny Fit Tuxedo Pants", this is present in one cell in a particular row. Similarly many items are there but with different names

Comment: Take a look at MS docs on the [like operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx) or this guide to [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below (using `RegEx` object to find exact matches to "Pin").

The RegEx Pattern is `.Pattern = "\bPin\b"`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindPinOnly()

Dim C As Range
Dim RegEx As Object, Match As Object

Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\bPin\b"  ' Match exactly "Pin" without extra letters
End With

For Each C In Range("A1:J10000") '<-- loop through all cells in Range
    Set Match = RegEx.Execute(C.Value)

    If Match.Count >= 1 Then
        C.Interior.ColorIndex = 46 '<-- in my tests I just colored the cells in Red
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

**Note**: don't be afraid of the loop here, it took less than a second to complete the run of this code.

---

**Edit 1**: Allow using the `RegEx` with multiple words, and color only the specific word's font in red (and not the enitre cell)

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRegex()
' This sub is to test the RegEx with multile words (from an array)

Dim StrArr, Elem As Variant

' add words below to array (can add words to array using a Range of cells)
StrArr = Array("Belt", "Shoes", "Sunglass", "Pin")

For Each Elem In StrArr '<-- loop through all elements in array and use RegEx sub to find them in the Range
    Call FindWordOnly(Elem)
Next Elem

End Sub

'========================================================================

Sub FindWordOnly(str As Variant)

Dim C As Range
Dim RegEx As Object, Match As Object

Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\b" & str & "\b"  ' Match exactly "Pin" without extra letters
End With

For Each C In Range("A1:J10000") '<-- loop through all cells in Range
    Set Match = RegEx.Execute(C.Value)

    If Match.Count >= 1 Then
        ' === only modify the "found" text inside the cell to Red ===
         Dim StartChar As Long

         StartChar = InStr(1, C.Value, str)
         C.Characters(Start:=StartChar, Length:=Len(str)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)    
    End If   
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Just like "Pin", I will be filtering many data on by one. Like Belt, Shoes, Sunglass, etc. So macro is not the answer.

Comment: ofcourse it is, you just have'nt give it a chance. I'll edit it and show you the possibilites

Comment: @matangraj did you try the edited code under **Edit 1** ? is that good for your needs ? testing with many optional words

Answer (score 2):

Some good VBA solutions given. Here is formula option which will give you a `True` if exactly `Pin` is found, or `False` otherwise (it's not case sensitive).

If you have a string in `A1`, you can place this in `B1` and drag down. (You can place it in `K1` or anything really if that's easier)

```
=OR(OR(LEFT(A1,4)="Pin ",RIGHT(A1,3)="pin"),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" pin ",A1))))
```

Here's how it works:

1. Checks if `pin` (with a space after) can be found at the beginning or exactly `pin` can be found at the end of the string.
2. checks if `pin` (with spaces either side) can be found somewhere in the middle of the string.
3. Return true in either of these cases, false otherwise.

Clearly at this point you can just filter on the `True` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with AutoFilter.
With the **or** **criteria** you can say that you want all *Pin* that have a space bevor or a space after the Word. So you can get all *Pin* Words.

The Code Would look like that:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabelle1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1 _
        :="=** Pink**", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=**Pink **"
```

Comment: You need to loop through all Columns, so you'll need a `For` loop on `Field` for putting the Criteria1 `"Pin" in each column.

Comment: @moosli Just like "Pin", I will be filtering many data on by one. Like Belt, Shoes, Sunglass, etc. So macro is not the answer.

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

When using auto filter:

Text Filters > Custom Filter... >

```
contains         ▼  |Pin | '(this contains a single space after the word)
  ○ And   ◙ Or
ends with        ▼  |Pin|  '(without the single space)
```

Which will give you the desired result